# Pass variables to Flask's render_template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to pass multiple variables from my Flask view to my Jinja template. Right now, I can only pass one. How do I pass multiple variable when rendering a template?

```
@app.route("/user/<user_id>/post/<post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def im_research(user_id, post_id):
    user = mongo.db.Users.find_one_or_404({'ticker': user_id})
    return render_template('post.html', user=user)
```

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The [`render_template`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.render_template) function takes any number of keyword arguments. Query for each of the things you need in the template, then pass the results of each query as another argument to `render_template`.

```py
@app.route("/user/<user_id>/post/<post_id>")
def im_research(user_id, post_id):
    user = get_user_by_id(id)
    post = get_user_post_by_id(user, id)
    return render_template("post.html", user=user, post=post)
```

---

Python also has a built-in `locals()` function that will return a dict of all locally defined variables. *This is not recommended* as it may pass too much and obscures what specifically is being passed.

```py
@app.route("/user/<user_id>/post/<post_id>")
def im_research(user_id, post_id):
    user = get_user_by_id(id)
    post = get_user_post_by_id(user, id)
    return render_template("post.html", **locals())
```

Answer (score 25):

```
return render_template('im.html', user= None, content = xxx, timestamp = xxx)
```

You can pass as many variables as you need.
The [api](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/)

excerpt:

> flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context) 
>   Renders a
>   template from the template folder with the given context.
>
> Parameters:    template_name_or_list – the name of the template to be
>   rendered, or an iterable with template names the first one existing
>   will be rendered context – the variables that should be available in
>   the context of the template.

Answer (score 13):

It is also possible to pass a list to `render_template`'s context variables, and refer to its elements with Jinja's syntax in HTML.

example.py

```
mylist = [user, content, timestamp]
return render_template('exemple.html', mylist=mylist)
```

example.html

```
...
<body>
    {% for e in mylist %}
        {{e}}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables to Flask's render_template function, you can create a dictionary containing the variables you want to pass and then provide this dictionary as keyword arguments to render_template.
Here's how you can do it:

```
context = {
    'name': 'test',
    'age': '35'
}

render_template("index.html", **context)
```

In the template, you can access the variables directly:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
<p>You are {{ age }} years old.</p>
```